# PortletRequest Vaadin 7 and Liferay

Tags: liferay, vaadin, liferay-6, vaadin7

In Vaadin 6, 
you could override onRequestStart to obtain the PortletRequest object like so

```
@Override
    public void onRequestStart(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response)
```

In Vaadin 7, due to the portlet class change to com.vaadin.server.VaadinPortlet, there is no more onRequestStart to get the PortletReqeust object, just their new VaadinRequest object.

```
 @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request)
```

Issue is getting this to a PortletRequest to be used.  Anyone found a way to retrieve PortletRequest from Vaadin 7 and liferay?

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the information that a VaadinRequest is both VaadinPortletRequest and VaadinServletRequest, you can retrieve PortletRequest and HttpServletRequest as so:

```
        VaadinPortletRequest vprRequest = (VaadinPortletRequest) request;
        PortletRequest pRequest = vprRequest.getPortletRequest();

        VaadinServletRequest vsRequest = (VaadinServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletRequest hsRequest = vsRequest.getHttpServletRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do as well

```
PortletRequest currentPortlet = VaadinPortletService.getCurrentPortletRequest();
```